# How to add new Fields/Elements to JsonObject?

Tags: java, json, eclipse, gson

Here is my code. It is an attempt to read JSON using the **GSON** library.

```
 JsonReader reader = new JsonReader( new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object.getObjectContent())) );
reader.beginArray();
int gsonVal = 0;
while (reader.hasNext()) {
       JsonParser  _parser = new JsonParser();
       JsonElement jsonElement =  _parser.parse(reader);
    JsonObject jsonObject1 = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
}
```

Now, I need to add 2 additional fields to this `JsonObject`. I need to add `primary_key` field and `hash_index` field.

I tried the below, but it didn't work.

```
jsonObject1.add("hash_index", hashIndex.toString().trim()); 
jsonObject1.add("primary_key", i);
```

When these two values are added, the JsonObject will look like below.

```
{
        "hash_index": "00102x05h06l0aj0dw",
        "body": "Who's signing up for Obamacare?",
        "_type": "ArticleItem",
        "title": "Who's signing up for Obamacare? - Jan. 13, 2014",
        "source": "money.cnn.com",
        "primary_key": 0,
        "last_crawl_date": "2014-01-14",
        "url": "http://money.cnn.com/2014/01/13/news/economy/obamacare-enrollment/index.html"
    }
```

How can I do this? This is my first time with GSON.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use the JsonObject#addProperty()

```
 final JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
 json.addProperty("type", "ATP");
```

In Your case

```
jsonObject1.addProperty("hash_index", hashIndex.toString().trim()); 
jsonObject1.addProperty("primary_key", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`put`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#put%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) method.

```
jsonObject1.put("hash_index", hashIndex.toString().trim()); 
jsonObject1.put("primary_key", i);
```

From your comment it's look like you have to use `addProperty` method.

```
jsonObject1.addProperty("hash_index", hashIndex.toString().trim()); 
jsonObject1.addProperty("primary_key", i);
```

Comment: Hi, That is for Json. This is Json Via `GSON`.

Answer (score 0):

Use put method. `jsonObject1.put("hash_index", hashIndex.toString().trim()); 
jsonObject1.put("primary_key", i);`

Comment: Hi, That is for Json. This is Json Via `GSON`.